# QMimeData::hasImage() always returning false

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to change a `QGraphicsObject`'s image by dropping an image on it. But `QMimeData::hasImage()` always return false even when I drag and drop an image from hard disk or internet browser.

```
birdItem::birdItem(QGraphicsItem *parent)
    : QGraphicsObject(parent)
{
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    item = new QImage(":/images/bird.png");
    setPos(mapFromScene(100, 450));
    setCursor(QCursor(Qt::PointingHandCursor));
}

void birdItem::dropEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    if (event -> mimeData() -> hasImage()) {
        qDebug() << "got Image";
        item = new QImage(qvariant_cast<QImage>(event -> mimeData() ->   imageData()));
        update();
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "not an Image";
}

void birdItem::dragEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneDragDropEvent *event)
{
    if (event -> mimeData() -> hasImage()) {
            qDebug() << "got an Image enter EVnet";
            event -> setAccepted(true);
            update();
    }
    else
        qDebug() << "not an image eneter event";
}
```

I always get that I didn't drop an image. I tried dragging png and jpg images but I don't know if format matters here. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: 1) You're leaking memory like crazy. Do not "new" QImages. 2) dump what are the metatypes available in the drag event? Pretty sure you don't get image, just the file URL.